# ReportViewer filter by Parameter not accepting parameter's value

Tags: c#, asp.net, reportviewer

I'm having an issue with my report giving an error when I try to pass it a parameter value that I get from the query string.

With the current settings below I am getting the following error: "An error has occurred during report processing.
 Failed to evaluate the FilterValue of the Tablix ‘Tablix2’"

In my designer I have a table with columns dragged from the dataset.
I have a textbox and the label is the parameter CHAPTER_ID. It shows up as "#Error". Both when I set it as integer or Text

The table populates fine, but cannot filter using the parameter. I can Hardcode a value and it filters.

ASPX

```
<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewerAnyReport" runat="server" Height="800px" ProcessingMode="Local"
        Style="position: relative" Width="1100px"></rsweb:ReportViewer>
```

ASPX.CS

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!(Page.IsPostBack))
        {
            List<GetComments_Result> comments = RexCommentBAO.GetAllComments();
            string s_chapterId = Request.QueryString["ChapterID"];

            try
            {
                ReportDataSource datasource = new ReportDataSource("ds_comments", comments);
                ReportViewerAnyReport.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(datasource);

                ReportViewerAnyReport.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = @"C:\Work\W2R.Rex\Rex\Rex\Rex_Web\RexReports.rdlc"; 
                ReportViewerAnyReport.LocalReport.ReportPath = @"C:\Work\W2R.Rex\Rex\Rex\Rex_Web\RexReports.rdlc";

                ReportParameter p = new ReportParameter("CHAPTER_ID", s_chapterId);
                this.ReportViewerAnyReport.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { p });
                ReportViewerAnyReport.LocalReport.Refresh();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

In my rdlc [Design] --

Parameters Properties

```
General Tab:
     Name: CHAPTER_ID
     Data type: Text (Tried Integer - codebehind passes string. Integer throws the error: "An error has occurred during report processing.  Failed to evaluate the FilterValue of the Tablix ‘Tablix2’".

 Checkboxes (all unchecked)
     -Allow Blank value("")
     -Allow null value
     -Allow multiple values

  Available Values Tab: None is selected
  Default Values Tab: None is selected
```

Tablix properties:

```
General Tab: 
    Dataset name: ds_comments
Filters Tab:  
    Expression: Fields!CHAPTER_ID.Value  Text (Tried Integer)
    Operator: =
    Value: [@CHAPTER_ID] - the expression for this value is "=Parameters!CHAPTER_ID.Value". Hard coded a value and it filtered the data.
```

Answer (score 0):

So it appears that you can't use Parameters when doing LocalReport. Changed it by passing in the datasource pre filtered.

```
List<CMT> comments = RexCommentBAO.GetCommentsByChapterId(i_chapterId);
```